# ¿Como Extraer Los Datos Que Porta Un "Label" Con Python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Quiero extraer los talles de un producto y estos mismos están en un "label" intente varias formas para extraer la información del talle pero no lo consigo.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as b

#Registro En Pagina
headers = {
"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36",
"Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate",
"Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
"DNT":"1"
}

url = 'https://www.grid.com.ar/zapatillas-nike-air-max-pre-day-running-mujer-3160274/p'
 
#Se Entra A La Pagina
html = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
contenido = html.content
soup = b(contenido,"lxml")

talles = []

post = soup.find('div',{'class':'row product-details'})
talles.append(post.find('label',{'class':'dimension-Talle espec_0 skuespec_34P5 skuespec_Talle_opcao_34.5 skuespec_Talle_opcao_34P5'}))
print(talles.text)
```

Esto fue lo ultimo que intente por lo menos para sacar un talle pero tampoco funciona.

En la pagina los talles estan declarados así

```
<input type="radio" name="20392_Talle" dimension="Talle" data-value="34.5" data-dimension="Talle" class="skuselector-specification-label input-dimension-Talle sku-selector skuespec_34P5 change-image" id="20392_Talle_0" value="34.5" specification="34P5">
<label for="20392_Talle_0" class="dimension-Talle espec_0 skuespec_34P5 skuespec_Talle_opcao_34.5 skuespec_Talle_opcao_34P5" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html="true" title="" data-original-title="ARG: 34.5 <br> USA: 5 ">34.5</label>
<input type="radio" name="20392_Talle" dimension="Talle" data-value="35" data-dimension="Talle" class="skuselector-specification-label input-dimension-Talle sku-selector skuespec_35 change-image" id="20392_Talle_1" value="35" specification="35">
<label for="20392_Talle_1" class="dimension-Talle espec_0 skuespec_35 skuespec_Talle_opcao_35 skuespec_Talle_opcao_35" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html="true" title="" data-original-title="ARG: 35 <br> USA: 5.5 ">35</label>
```

Comment: se borro en lo que están los talles, como se ve en la parte de html estan en "label" y intente extraer los datos del input y del label pero no lo consigo dejo la web por si alguno la necesita ```https://www.grid.com.ar/zapatillas-nike-air-max-pre-day-running-mujer-3160274/p```

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesaria, por favor ingresa en tu pregunta la información que pusiste en tu comentario anterior.

Comment: Para clarificar, ¿Estás buscando obtener `34.5` y `35` únicamente?

Comment: El problema es que estas tratando de obtener elementos generados por javascript, lo que hacen los webscraping es obtener los elementos html de una pagina no el DOM que es el html generado despues de javascript

Comment: @HeytalePazguato si trato de extraer 34.5 y 35

Comment: @RafaelBautista Claro pero no podria de alguna manera sacar el valor que presenta ? datos como "data-original-title" del label o "value" del input ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A veces la información que necesitas puede estar escondida en un tag `<script>`. Por eso es recomendable que hagas un `print(soup)` y hacer *ctrl+f* para ver si se encuentra el dato solicitado en la respuesta de la solicitud al sitio.
Eso mismo hice para ver si podía encontrar los talles y veo que se encuentran en un tag `script`.

Entonces, buscar el script que contiene los datos deseados..
para cada "script" vamos a buscar el que contenga `"var skuJson_0"`, ya que es el que contiene la información.

```
r = soup.find(lambda script: script.name == 'script' and 'var skuJson_0' in str(script))

for data in extract_json_objects(str(r)):
    pass
```

La función `extract_json_objects()` la saqué de la increible respuesta de [Martijn Pieters♦](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54235803/11539076)

```
from json import JSONDecoder

def extract_json_objects(text, decoder=JSONDecoder()):
    
    """Find JSON objects in text, and yield the decoded JSON data
    Does not attempt to look for JSON arrays, text, or other JSON types outside
    of a parent JSON object. 
    """
    pos = 0
    while True:
        match = text.find('{', pos)
        if match == -1:
            break
        try:
            result, index = decoder.raw_decode(text[match:])
            yield result
            pos = match + index
        except ValueError:
            pos = match + 1
```

Y ahora en `data`. tenes toda la info, por ej:

```
print(data['dimensionsMap']['Talle'])

['34.5', '35', '35.5', '36.5', '37', '37.5', '38', '39', '39.5', '40', '41']
```

Y si por ejemplo revisas el diccionario, puedes hacer crear un DataFrame, a partir del mismo, y mostrar sus columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data['skus'])
print(df.columns)
Index(['sku', 'skuname', 'dimensions', 'available', 'availablequantity',
       'cacheVersionUsedToCallCheckout', 'listPriceFormated',
       'fullSellingPrice', 'listPrice', 'taxFormated', 'taxAsInt',
       'bestPriceFormated', 'bestPrice', 'spotPrice', 'installments',
       'installmentsValue', 'installmentsInsterestRate', 'image', 'sellerId',
       'seller', 'measures', 'unitMultiplier', 'rewardValue'],
      dtype='object')
```

| sku | skuname | dimensions | available | availablequantity | cacheVersionUsedToCallCheckout |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 125348 | 316-0274-05.0 | {'Talle': '34.5'} | True | 5 | A049A935AFE4145FA078725B6A185B4C_ |
| 125349 | 316-0274-05.5 | {'Talle': '35'} | True | 10 | A049A935AFE4145FA078725B6A185B4C_ |
| 125350 | 316-0274-06.0 | {'Talle': '35.5'} | True | 99999 | A049A935AFE4145FA078725B6A185B4C_ |
| 125351 | 316-0274-06.5 | {'Talle': '36.5'} | True | 99999 | A049A935AFE4145FA078725B6A185B4C_ |

Queda en ti revisar que datos son los que te sirven y cuales no

Comment: T-E-A-M-O Me Sirvió Muchísimas Gracias!